# JS: convert timezone to user-friendly

Tags: javascript

I use timezones to format dates, i.e. `America/Toronto`. The requirement is to display user-friendly format to users, i.e. `BST`, `EST`, etc.

How can it be converted?

I was trying the following approach:

```
const func = (date) => new Date(date)
  .toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
    day: '2-digit',
    timeZoneName: 'short',
  })
  .slice(4);
```

However, it does not show a correct zone. Thanks!

Comment: Hm? Not work how? For me when I run it with `new Date()` I get `CST`, which is correct.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat

Comment: if you include { timeZone: 'America/Toronto'} in the [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#options) it returns EST as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for [Toronto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones#TORONTO) it is **only** `EST` or `EDT`

```js
const
  refDteEST = '2022-01-14T19:20:21.000-05:00'  // Eastern Standard Time (Toronto) -> EST
, refDteEDT = '2022-08-14T19:20:21.000-04:00'  // Eastern Daylight Time (Toronto) -> EDT
  ;

const func = dte => 
  new Date( dte ) 
   .toLocaleDateString( 'en-US'
     , { day          : '2-digit'
       , timeZoneName : 'short'
       , timeZone     : 'America/Toronto' 
     } )
   .slice(4);

console.log( func(refDteEST) ) // EST
console.log( func(refDteEDT) ) // EDT
```